# View Controller not deallocated after adding GameKit

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, game-center, gamekit

My view controller no longer gets deallocated after adding the following:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) GKLocalPlayer *player;

(in viewDidLoad)
self.player = nil;
[self authenticatePlayer];

- (void)authenticatePlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];    
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(*localPlayer) *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;


    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
    ^(UIViewController *authenticateViewController, NSError *error)
    {
        if (authenticateViewController != nil)
        {
            [self presentViewController:authenticateViewController animated:YES
                             completion:nil];
        }
        else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {

            self.player = blockLocalPlayer;
            [self openGame];
        }
        else
        {
            // Disable Game Center
            self.player = nil;
            [self openGame];
        }
    };
}

- (void)setPlayer:(GKLocalPlayer *)player
{
    _player = player;
    NSString *playerName;
    if (_player)
    {
        playerName = _player.alias;
    }
    else
    {
        playerName = @"Anonymous Player";
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", playerName]);
}
```

The problem occurs whether or not the user connects to game center. There must be something in the code that is causing the view controller to remain in memory after it gets dismissed. If I comment these lines out:

```
self.player = nil;
[self authenticatePlayer];
```

the view controller will properly get deallocated when dismissed.

EDIT:
My hunch was correct. From Apple docs:

> Game Kit maintains a strong reference to your completion handler even
>   after successfully authenticating a local player. If your game moves
>   into the background, Game Kit automatically authenticates the player
>   again whenever your game moves back to the foreground. Game Kit calls
>   your same completion handler each time it authenticates the local
>   player. Be mindful that in block programming, any Objective-C object
>   referenced inside a block is also strongly referenced by the block
>   until the block is released. Because Game Kit maintains a strong
>   reference to your completion handler until your game terminates, any
>   objects referenced from within your authentication handler are also
>   held indefinitely.

This is a problem for me though. I'm using Cocos2d and it has problems resetting its view unless the view controller is completely deallocated and created fresh.

Is there any way to get Game Kit to let go of my view controller?

Comment: Where and how are you declaring authenticateViewController, and how is it dismissed?

Comment: AFAIK, it's part of the GameKit framework.

Comment: ok, crickets so far on this question. How about this - what would cause any view controller to not get deallocated when calling self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO?

Comment: Something else has a strong pointer to it. I'll ask my question again -- how is authenticateViewController dismissed?

Comment: It dismisses itself. It's part of GameKit. Also, even in the cases where authenticateViewController is nil (when Game Center is disabled), I still have the same issue.

Comment: Well there's nothing in the code you posted that looks like it should retain your controller. If you comment out the two cases of [self openGame], does that cause your controller to be deallocated when dismissed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got sick of dealing with the issue and moved the GameKit authentication code to a different view controller, where it is not vital that it be deallocated.